# Is there a way to change the beamer strut and footer like the image below

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, frame-title, examdesign

```
\documentclass[12pt,dvipsnames,usenames,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usebeamercolor{default}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\definecolor{clementine}{HTML}{F26528}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=clementine,fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
    \nointerlineskip
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,ht=1.8em,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
        \vbox{}\vskip-2ex%
        \strut\insertframetitle\strut
        \vskip-0.8ex%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\title{My Big Title}
\subtitle{My Small Subtitle}
\author{Bada Panda}
\institute{{\tiny advised by}\\ \vspace{.10cm}Professor Marshmello Samwich}
\date{\scriptsize Stupid Systems Laboratory, University of Nowhere\\ \vspace{.10cm}\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}[plain]{}
\hspace*{-25pt}%
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{figures/Slideback_05.pdf}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

It would be nice if I could

1. Change the colors for the strip and text
2. The big number on the left is the section number
3. The small number below it is slide in that section
4. Change the globe icon/pick from 4 icons

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sure it's possible to do this but it would be quite a bit of work. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX-SE. Yes, it is not too difficult to create something of that sort. Of course, I do not have the graphics you include.

```
\documentclass[12pt,dvipsnames,usenames,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usebeamercolor{default}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\definecolor{clementine}{HTML}{F26528}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=clementine,fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
\centerline{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[clementine] (0,1.8) -- (1,0.8) -| (\paperwidth,-0.8) -- (1,-0.8) --
    (0,-1.8) -- cycle;
    \node[anchor=east] at (1.5,0) {\includegraphics[width=1.2cm]{example-image-duck}};
    \draw[thick,white] (1.6,1.01) -- (1.6,-1.01);
    \node[text=white,anchor=west,font=\Large\sffamily] at (2,0) {\insertframetitle};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}

\title{My Big Title}
\subtitle{My Small Subtitle}
\author{Bada Panda}
\institute{{\tiny advised by}\\ \vspace{.10cm}Professor Marshmello Samwich}
\date{\scriptsize Stupid Systems Laboratory, University of Nowhere\\ \vspace{.10cm}\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Rodent}
blah blah blah

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot